# Is there an ActiveMerchant for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, payment-gateway, activemerchant

What payment gateway library works with Sinatra if you're looking to add ecommerce functionality to your app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) works excellently as a stand-alone library, as well as a Rails plugin.

> It was developed to for (sic) usage in Ruby
>   on Rails web applications and
>   integrates seamlessly as a plugin but
>   it also works excellently as a stand
>   alone library.

```
gem install activemerchant
```